# Не работает корректно замена символов в задачке на шифрование с обратным алфавитом

Tags: java, шифрование

Имеется задача на шифрование, где каждый из входящих в строку символов английского алфавита надо заменить на его "зеркальный", т.е. такой же по номеру с конца - `a→z, b→y, c→x, ... x→c, y →b, z→a`.

Попробовал сделать это без массивов или списков, через строки - в результате замена работает только для последней части алфавита, т.е. символы с `n` по `z` меняет на нужные, а символы с `a` по `m` - нет, оставляя их в первозданном виде.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String initialPhrase = scanner.nextLine().trim();
        String encryptedPhrase = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < initialPhrase.length(); i++) {
            encryptedPhrase += String.valueOf(encrypt(initialPhrase.charAt(i), alphabet));
        }

        System.out.println(encryptedPhrase);
    }

    public static char encrypt(char ch, String str) {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (ch == str.charAt(i)) {
                ch = str.charAt(str.length() - i - 1);
            }
        }
        return ch;
    }
}
```

Кто-нибудь может объяснить, почему метод `encrypt(ch, str)` срабатывает только для второй половины алфавита?

Comment: Возможно и по самому алгоритму будет полезен совет, сейчас его сложность O(n*m) хотя можно сделать за O(n). Пробежав по каждому char строки и заменив его на (219 -  chars[i]). 219 это 'a' + 'z'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if (ch == str.charAt(i)) {
        ch = str.charAt(str.length() - i - 1);
    }
}
```

Необходимо реализовать выход из цикла после того, как значение переменной `ch` было обновлено, иначе для первой половины оно меняется дважды (туда и обратно).

Comment: Понял, спасибо! Надо в цикле после строки с `ch = str.charAt(str.length() - i - 1);` строку `break;` добавить. Иначе при этом же значении `i` мы символ из первой половины алфавита "отзеркаливаем" в его "отражение", а затем снова находим его и "отзеркаливаем" обратно.